# How can I find the quantile of the top 1%

Tags: r

I have the concentration mean of 5ng/kg with an SD of 1.6ng/kg
Im not sure how to approach this problem. Im a beginner in r so I dont have much experience to fall back on
I havent been able to figure the problem out enough to try it yet

Comment: Are you asking how one calculates the value for a quantile given a known mean and SD, but no raw observed data?